# logging the windows shutdown sequence operations

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, system-shutdown

we're working on a hardware platform that freezes during windows shutdown.

I'd like to be able to log what's happening (e.g. to identify if there's a problem with ACPI, or a windows driver etc).

What tools can I use to log the windows shutdown sequence?

Answer (score 0):

You might get some mileage out of `VerboseStatus` and `DisableStatusMessages` registry values:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/325376

Which version of Windows are you testing?

Comment: unfortunately, that link is only relevant to the server platforms.

Comment: VerboseStatus still works for Windows 7 (I just checked) but admittedly doesn't give you much detail. You could also look at System messages in the Windows event log. What's the last thing displayed when it freezes?

Comment: User selects restart from start menu, system shuts down any remaining processes and exits, windows is shutting down message is displayed, wait circle mouse cursor spins then eventually freezes.  It seems to be a driver unload problem, and we want to be able to identify the driver.

Comment: If it doesn't happen in safe mode, I would try disabling groups of drivers in Device Manager to narrow down the problem.